# What is the purpose of type arguments in constructor call following new?

Tags: java

In the Java specification (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), new has the following form:

```
ClassInstanceCreationExpression ::=
| new TypeArguments_opt TypeDeclSpecifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamond_opt
    ( ArgumentListopt ) ClassBodyopt
| Primary . new TypeArguments_opt Identifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamond_opt
    ( ArgumentListopt ) ClassBodyopt
```

What is the purpose of the first optional type argument list after the new?  I was not able to find it from my read of section 15.9 (all references to type arguments list seem to refer to the list after the type/identifier).  Testing out random bits on the standard Java compiler yields confusing results:

```
public class Foo<T> { }
// ...
Foo<Integer> t1 = new <Integer> Foo<Integer>();  // works
Foo<Integer> t2 = new <Integer> Foo();           // works -- unchecked warning missing the type arg after Foo
Foo<Integer> t3 = new <Boolean> Foo<Integer>();  // works
Foo<Integer> t4 = new <Float, Boolean> Foo<Integer>();  // works
Foo<Integer> t5 = new <NotDefined> Foo<Integer>();  // fails -- NotDefined is undefined
```

On theses simple examples, it doesn't seem like this first parameter list does anything meaningful although it parses and checks for the validity of its arguments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Constructors can declare type parameters too

```
public class Main {     
    public static class Foo<T> {
        public <E> Foo(T object, E object2) {

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo<Integer> foo = new <String> Foo<Integer>(1, "hello");           
    }    
}
```

That's what the `<String>` preceding the constructor call is for. It is the type argument for the constructor.

The following

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new <String> Foo<Integer>(1, new Object());
```

fails with

> The parameterized constructor Foo(Integer, String) of type
>   Main.Foo is not applicable for the arguments (Integer,
>   Object)

In your last

```
Foo<Integer> t5 = new <NotDefined> Foo<Integer>();  // fails -- NotDefined is undefined
```

`NotDefined` is just not a type that is found during compilation. If it was, it would just give you a warning that it is `unused`.

Comment: Excellent.  That makes sense.  What is still confusing is that you can supply type parameters to a constructor invocation that does not specify any type arguments.  What are the rules there?

Comment: The Eclipse compiler just warns `Unused type arguments for the non generic constructor`. In a similar fashion to methods with type parameters, you don't have to specify the `<...>` if it can be inferred from the type of the argument.

Comment: Ah.  Interesting.  `javac` doesn't give any warnings (even with -Xlint:warnings on) for it which is likely the root of my confusion.  I find it strange that you can "over-specify" type parameters like this (i.e., supply type parameters that the constructor does not use).  Regardless, it is what it is, I guess.  Thanks!  (I assume that the reason why Java allows this is related to generic type erasure.  If anyone else can fill in the details, that would be great!)

Answer (score 3):

You can add useless type arguments for method invocations, weird stuff like

```
Math.<Runnable>max(1,2);

System.out.<Button>println();
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1-200-E

*a non-generic method may be potentially applicable to an invocation that supplies explicit type arguments. Indeed, it may turn out to be applicable. In such a case, the type arguments will simply be ignored.*

*This rule stems from issues of compatibility and principles of substitutability. Since interfaces or superclasses may be generified independently of their subtypes, we may override a generic method with a non-generic one. However, the overriding (non-generic) method must be applicable to calls to the generic method, including calls that explicitly pass type arguments. Otherwise the subtype would not be substitutable for its generified supertype.*