# Java generics infers Object for nested method call instead of T if nested method argument is not typesafe

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, inferred-type

today I have ran into strange `javac` behavior regarding generic type inference. Here's example class to ilustrate this strange behavior:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Test {

    protected <T> T strange(T t, Map<String, String> map) {
        return t;
    }

    protected void ok(Map<String, String> map) {}
    protected <T> T test(T t) {
        T res = strange(t , new HashMap<String, String>());
        //Doesn't work
        //res = strange(t, new <String, String>HashMap());
        ok(new <String, String>HashMap());
        res = strange(t, Collections.<String, String>emptyMap());
        //Doesn't work
        //res = strange(t, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        res = strange(t, (Map<String, String>) Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        ok(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Notice `//Doesn't work` comments. If you uncomment this code you will get strange compiler error:

```
Test.java:18: error: incompatible types
        res = strange(t, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
                     ^
  required: T
  found:    Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>test(T)
```

Strange thing is that error complains about `strange` method return type is Object and not T, but when second unsafe parameter is cast to correct type then T is inferred correctly.

Can someone explain if this is correct behavior? Because it looks strange to me. Can it be a compiler bug?

Why this line works

```
T res = strange(t , new HashMap<String, String>());
```

and this one is doesn't?

```
T res = strange(t, new <String, String>HashMap());
```

I have tested it with java 7 and 6.

Comment: Java has syntax rules. This `new HashMap<String, String>());`  is completely different than `new <String, String>HashMap());`.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Oh I see now. It is described in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688882/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-arguments-in-constructor-call-following-new/18688969#18688969). But this doesn't answer my original question about problem that Object is infered instead of T

Comment: That's not the only reason. I'll try to write something up soon.

Answer (score 5):

The root cause is the use of Raw Types.

When you do this

```
new <String, String>HashMap()
```

The type arguments `<String, String>` are [constructor type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688882/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-arguments-in-constructor-call-following-new/18688969#18688969), not class arguments. You can very well do

```
new <String, String, String, String, Integer, Foo, Bar, String>HashMap()
```

since the `HashMap` constructor does not declare any type parameters.

However, because you haven't provided the class type arguments, you're effectively using a raw type. The [Java Language Specification says this about raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.

The basic idea is that if you use a raw type with some generic method, the generic types of the method are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So using

```
res = strange(t, new <String, String>HashMap());
```

makes your method look like

```
protected Object strange(Object t, Map map) {
    return t;
}
```

to the compiler.

and you are trying to do

```
/* T */ res = strange(t, new <String, String>HashMap());
```

You can't assign `Object` to a reference of type `T` because you don't know what `T` is. The compiler therefore throws an exception.

Related

- [Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods)
- [Raw types with generic methods independent of the generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655806/raw-types-with-generic-methods-independent-of-the-generic-type)
- [Java generic methods in generics classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001550/java-generic-methods-in-generics-classes)

Comment: Great answer. I agree on explanation of `new <String, String>HashMap()`. But regarding return type inference for me it seems strange that single raw parameter of Map which is not related to inferred type T causes compiler to think that method will return Object instead of T

Comment: @Antanas Rule of thumb: whenever a raw type is involved, every generic type is erased.